# I need instruction on moving unallocated space for nuewbies (or dummies)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have followed instruction after instruction and just end up with more partitions (see screenshot) I am handicapped homeless couch surfer who spends most days in the library I am on an older model donated Dell Levono laptop so purchasing anything soft or hardware is nigh on to impossible. I detest Windows 10 and so dual booted Ubuntu until I can maintain enough proficiency to ditch the Win10. I just wanted to transfer more space from Windows to Ubuntu..  I had a Linux based tablet decades ago but never had time to figure it all out.  Now I have nothing but time.  Many of the Youtube instructors either talk too fast or start above my level (so far).  I prefer sites where I can cut and past the elaborate terminal scripts for now. I have experience on both MAC and WiN but 10 was just the final "upgrade" too many.  I was considered a guru in MS-office until the 2003 release.  I am not programmer but have been bringing my nursing colleagues into the 21st century kicking all the way.  Soooo, I am neither technologically challenged nor am I a candidate for IT.  Please Please please can anyone help me.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmRUr.jpg)

Comment: What is your desired outcome? Suggest you [edit] your question to remove all the editorial fluff and focus on the technical question. "My system is like this and I want it to be like this, how do I do it?"

Comment: Thanks OM still learning will do.

Answer (score 0):

To move space from Windows to Ubuntu you need to do the following:

1. Backup any data you cannot afford to lose
2. In Windows use Disk Management to reduce the size of your Windows partition. You may need to temporarily turn off hibernation and swap space to make immovable files movable. Don’t take too much space from Windows. It will not work well.
3. Make Ubuntu install media, usb or cd. The Ubuntu install guide will tell you how to do this.
4. Boot your install media, choose try Ubuntu to enter a live session. You will probably need to get into your BIOS to do this by selecting the device to boot.
5. In the live session run GParted. Ubuntu (sda5) is inside an extended partition (sda4). There should be some unallocated space between sda2 and sda4 as a result of reducing the Windows partition. First you need to resize sda4 using all the space between sda2 and sda3. Finally resize sda5 to use all the space in sda4

Good luck!